# problem with nan in python ( pandas) the program can't recognize the nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I stock in strange situation

i have Data frame , some of the values are nulls

when I try do change the null , i cant do it , for some reason the console dosent recognize the null

**for example:**

```
df["volume_fermentor"]=df["volume_fermentor"].replace(np.nan,999)
```

when i run it , the console success do it but nothing change in the data frame

**another example:**

```
df["volume_fermentor"][4]

Out[79]: nan

df["volume_fermentor"][4]==df["volume_fermentor"][4]

Out[80]: False

df["volume_fermentor"][4]==np.nan

Out[81]: False'
```

Comment: Use [`df["volume_fermentor"].fillna(999)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) ?

Comment: You sure it’s not the string `'nan'`

Comment: Note that a NaN is not equal to itself (i.e. `np.nan == np.nan` is always false. Test it!). That explains the second part of your example (also, it is important to remember that any comparison with a nan is false, so `1 < np.nan` is false, as well as `1 >= np.nan`). That is why your use of `replace` does not work. Try @MichaelSzczesny solution. It should work. As a side note, this behaviour of NaNs is a requirement of IEEE 754.

Comment: Both your examples are completely valid, and show no issues (except for a trailing single quote in the last output). See the above comment: you can't compare directly to `np.nan`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare directly to a NaN: a NaN equals nothing, not even itself.

Use `np.isnan` instead (or equivalent functionality in Pandas):

```
>>> np.isnan(df["volume_fermentor"][4])
True
```

For a Pandas dataframe or series as a whole, you can use

```
df.isnull()
```

and

```
s.isnull()
```

respectively. That will yield a dataframe or series of boolean values, `True` for each NaN.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing to the same issue, the solution was to use `str()`.

In your case: `str(df["volume_fermentor"][4])==np.nan`

Comment: A string is not equal to a NumPy NaN constant. In fact, nothing is equal to `np.nan`.

Comment: unlike what you seem to be suggesting here, `np.nan == "nan"` actually equates to `False`. Did you mean to suggest `str(df["volume_fermentor"][4])==str(np.nan)` ?